# How to bring json format to relational form?

Tags: json, pyspark

this is my code:

```
%spark.pyspark

df_principalBody = spark.sql("""
 SELECT
      gtin
      , principalBodyConstituents
      --, principalBodyConstituents.coatings.materialType.value
    FROM
      v_df_source""")

df_principalBody.createOrReplaceTempView("v_df_principalBody")

df_principalBody.collect();
```

And this is the output:

```
[Row(gtin='7617014161936', principalBodyConstituents=[Row(coatings=[Row(materialType=Row(value='003', valueRange='405')
```

How can I read the value and valueRange fields in relational format?
I tried with explode and flatten, but it will not work.

Part of my json:

```
{
  "gtin": "7617014161936",
  "timePeriods": [
    {
      "fractionData": {
        "principalBody": {
          "constituents": [
            {
              "coatings": [
                {
                  "materialType": {
                    "value": "003",
                    "valueRange": "405"
                  },
                  "percentage": 0.1
                }
              ],
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data_dict.items()` to list key/value pairs.

I used part of your json as below -

```
str1 = """{"gtin": "7617014161936","timePeriods": [{"fractionData": {"principalBody": {"constituents": [{"coatings": [
                {
                  "materialType": {
                    "value": "003",
                    "valueRange": "405"
                  },
                  "percentage": 0.1
                }
             ]}]}}}]}"""
```

```
import json

res = json.loads(str1)

res_dict = res['timePeriods'][0]['fractionData']['principalBody']['constituents'][0]['coatings'][0]['materialType']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=res_dict.items())
```

**Output :**

```
+----------+---+
|        _1| _2|
+----------+---+
|     value|003|
|valueRange|405|
+----------+---+
```

You can even specify your schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(res_dict.items(), 
                      schema=StructType(fields=[
                          StructField("key", StringType()), 
                          StructField("value", StringType())])).show()
```

Resulting in

```
+----------+-----+
|       key|value|
+----------+-----+
|     value|  003|
|valueRange|  405|
+----------+-----+
```